# Is there a package.json key to define location of static assets

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I believe there are some non-standard package.json keys out in the wild (like `unpkg` or `jsnext`). I think there's even one for `style`.

Is there any pseudo standard out there that others are using to define the location in their packages where static assets (images, fonts, etc.) live?

Something like:

```js
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "assets": "dist/static"
}
```

Comment: I too have seen this in the wild, but I personally would not recommend inventing new `package.json` properties, what happens if NPM decides to use `assets` for it's own purpose? Reusing the `package.json` to store project information is a cute concept, but will likely confuse other people when they end up maintaining the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`directories`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#directories) or [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) key for that.

```
"files": [
  "./src/assets/"
],
"directories": {
   "assets:": "./src/assets"
}
```

Comment: Well `files` is what tells `npm` or `yarn` to publish to the registry. I do like the use of `directories` since it's an object and can take any key.